# How to type a function in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, types, typescript-typings

I have a list of objects with each an action field, I want to simplify this field of:

```js
    {
        id: '2',
        label: '',
        text: () => translate('MapAnnotation.Circle'),
        icon: 'circle',
        action: () => {
            optionsActionConstructor(MenuType.DRAW, GeometryType.CIRCLE);
        },
    }
```

to:

```js
    {
        id: '2',
        label: '',
        text: () => translate('MapAnnotation.Circle'),
        icon: 'circle',
        action: optionsActionConstructor(MenuType.DRAW, GeometryType.CIRCLE);

    }
```

So I did this :

```js
type ActionType = (type?: MenuType, tool?: DrawGeometryType | OtherToolsType) => any;

export interface OptionsButtons {
    id: string;
    label: string;
    text: () => string;
    icon: AvailableIcons;
    action: ActionType;
}
```

```js
const optionsActionConstructor = (
    type: MenuType.DRAW,
    tool: DrawGeometryType | OtherToolsType,
): void => {
    openedLeftMenuVar({ type, tool });
    if (isAOtherToolsType(tool)) {
        mapAnnotationsModalStatusVar({
            open: true,
            category: tool,
            annotation: null,
        });
    }
    if (isAGeometryType(tool)) {
        drawAnnotationVar({
            isActive: true,
            geometryType: tool,
        });
    }
};
```

It makes more sense to execute the function directly rather than going through an intermediate annotated function. But typescript doesn’t think like me and signals me :

Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ActionType'
OptionsMenu.types.ts(10, 5): The expected type comes from property 'action' which is declared here on type 'OptionsButtons'

Does anyone have a solution, please ? :/

Comment: I seems that you declare action to be a function returning something (`any`) but somewhere you are passing to action a function that returns nothing

Comment: Where is the code for your optionsActionConstructor?  Likely it is missing a return type.

You probably need something like:

`optionsActionConstructor(arg1: any, arg2: any): ActionType { }`

Note the return type at the end of the function definition : ActionType

Comment: Please stop posting code as images. Please take a read of [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) to get a feeling of why this is bad practice.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, as plain text in the body of your post (
[please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)
). Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly type the function

```js
type ActionType = (type?: MenuType, tool?: DrawGeometryType | OtherToolsType) => void;

const optionsActionConstructor: ActionType = (type, tool) => {
    openedLeftMenuVar({ type, tool });
    if (isAOtherToolsType(tool)) {
        mapAnnotationsModalStatusVar({
            open: true,
            category: tool,
            annotation: null,
        });
    }
    if (isAGeometryType(tool)) {
        drawAnnotationVar({
            isActive: true,
            geometryType: tool,
        });
    }
};

const item = {
    id: '2',
    label: '',
    text: () => translate('MapAnnotation.Circle'),
    icon: 'circle',
    action: () => optionsActionConstructor(MenuType.DRAW, GeometryType.CIRCLE);
    // the action field should contain a function, not a value. Moreover, the optionsActionConstructor function does not return anything.
}
```